# Accessing result of async pipe in template from component code in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

In Angular 2 I have a component with a template.

In the component TypeScript code i create a Reactive Extensions Observable (`items$`) and use it in an `ngFor`-directive in the template with an async-pipe.

This way I do not have to worry about subscribing and unsubscribing myself.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async"></div>
...
</div>
```

Now from the component code I would like to access the list of items, but without subscribing to it. Is there a way from the template to hand back a copy of or reference to the items list?

Comment: I think now it not possible that... you will have to make a subscriptions on the .ts and store the result in a variable...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just do this in the component:

```
items$.pipe(tap(items => this.items = items);
```

This way, you don't subscribe to the stream, and can keep using async pipe, but if a new value is emitted it will be saved in `items` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular 4+ you can use special syntax with `as` (works for `*ngIf` as well):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async as items"></div>
  {{ items.length }} ...
</div>
```

See the example here https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: Yes, but I would like a reference to the entire list of items, and would like to access it in the component code (ts-file)

Comment: Then no, you'll need to make the subscription in the component.

Comment: Actually you can: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57199847/651555